# Python command line arguments linux

Tags: python, linux, command-line, terminal, arguments

I have this little program(I know there is a lot of errors):

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os.path
import sys

filearg = sys.argv[0]

if (filearg == ""):
    filearg = input("")

else:

    if (os.path.isfile(filearg)):
        print "File exist"

    else:
        print"No file"
        print filearg
        print "wasn't found"
```

If i start it by typing `python file.py testfile.txt`

the output will be always(even if the file doesn't exist):

```
File exist
```

If you don't know what iam want from this program, i want to print "File 'filename' wasn't found" if the file isn't exist and if it's exist iam wan't to print "File exist"

Any ideas to solve it?
Thanks

Comment: Too lazy to debug? `print filearg`...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It should be `sys.argv[1]` not `sys.argv[0]`:

```
filearg = sys.argv[1]
```

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.argv):

> The list of command line arguments passed to a Python script. **argv[0] is the script name** (it is operating system dependent whether this is a full pathname or not). If the command was executed using the -c command line option to the interpreter, argv[0] is set to the string '-c'. If no script name was passed to the Python interpreter, argv[0] is the empty string.

Comment: this is correct.  `sys.argv[0]` will always exist because it is the file that is currently being executed (the python script).  The first argument always starts at `sys.argv[1]`.

Answer (score 4):

The first argument is always the name of the file being executed. This is true for a number of programming languages, you need to use `sys.argv[1]`